# Probability of rolling a die

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

```
You have a fair die and do the following experiment:
    - Roll the die once; let x be the outcome.
    - Roll the die x times (independently); let y be the smallest outcome of these x rolls.
    - Roll the die y times (independently); let z be the largest outcome of these y rolls.
Determine:
     Pr(x = 1 and y = 2 and z = 3):
```

I've been trying to solve it for hours and I can't find a solution. Maybe I'm overthinking it and it's actually fairly simple.

I would like to get some hints on how to approach/solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: It is simple for these small numbers. The probability that $X=1$ and $Y=2$ is simply $(1/6)(1/6)$. Now you need to find the probability that if $2$ dice are tossed, the maximum result is $3$. Make a list of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the probability of getting a particular value for each variable.

For $x=1$ we need to roll a 1 with a single roll. So that's $\frac{1}{6}$.

For $y=2$ we need to roll a 2 with $x$ dice rolls. So we need to get a 2 with 1 roll. That's $\frac{1}{6}$.

For $z=3$ we need to roll a 3 with one of the rolls, and then something smaller than or equal to a 3 on the next roll. (We only have 2 rolls since $y=2$.) **Case 1**: The first roll is a 3, and the second roll is either 1, 2, or 3. The probability of this happening is $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{2}$. **Case 2**: The first roll is either 1 or 2; and the second roll is a 3. (If the first roll is 3 this is covered in the first case.) The probability of this happening is $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{6}$. Since either can happen the probability of $z=3$ is 
$(\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{6}) = \frac{5}{36}$.

So: P(x=1, y=2, z=3) = $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{5}{36} = \frac{5}{1296}$.

Comment: What about rolling 3 on second roll and something less than 3 on first?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it is still the same since the order does not matter. If the second roll lands on a 3, the first roll still has 3 choices {1,2,3} out of 6.

Comment: yes that is true, thus probability that max is 3 is probablity first roll is 3 and second is less than or equal to 3 OR first roll is less than 3 and second is 3. You only account for one of these cases. for example you dont include roll (2,3) in your calculation which would still give value z=3

Comment: Or right, that makes this twice as likely. Sorry about that! I'll correct the post. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: you double counted outcome both 3s (ie (3,3))

Answer (score 0):

Use fact that $P(X=1, Y=2, Z=3)=P(Z=3|X=1, Y=2)P(Y=2|X=1)P(X=1)$